# Can I just pass a request object to guzzle get request?

Tags: php, guzzle

For guzzle you can do: `$client->request(options here ...)` but if I already have a pre-built psr7 Request object can I just do:

`$client->request($ps7RequestObjectHere);`

Or is there some other method in which I could pass said request object to and have guzzle execute it, I would prefer async.

A use case for this is if I am doing a pool of requests and for some reason I get something like 502 back, instead of trying all the requests again, I can just take that request at that index in the array of requests and say: Do this one, and then if that still fails then throw an error or continue on down the line of requests left to do in said pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what can be seen from [github](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/6.3.0/src/ClientInterface.php#L27), there are `$client->send()` and `$client->sendAsync()` methods that receive PSR-7 request as an argument and do what you ask for.